# Placeholder Image for youtube-ios-player-helper

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

i am using youtube-ios-player-helper in my application and is there any way to set video placeholder image for video ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    VideoCell *cell= (VideoCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VideoCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }


//
    NSMutableDictionary* VideoDict;


        VideoDict  = [arrVideolist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [cell.playerView loadWithVideoId:VideoDict[@"video_url"]];

     tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api ?

Comment: @Larme i have uploaded a gif in my question... i want to set placeholder image instead of that white space

Comment: Put an UIImageView above to charge the preview/thumbnail (with SDWebImage for instance) and when the playerViewDelegate (`playerViewDidBecomeReady:`) is called, hide the UIImageView.